# Blank Image - Pansharpening Sentinel-2 imagery in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, pansharpening

Referring to [Pansharpening Sentinel-2 imagery in Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358308/pansharpening-sentinel-2-imagery-in-google-earth-engine/395575#395575) and the solution provided

In the answer the code mentioned refers to the use of a single image, instead, I am trying to use it on image collection, for which I wrote the following code:

```js
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2') // searches all sentinel 2 imagery pixels...
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 10)) // ...filters on the metadata for pixels less than 10% cloud
  .filterDate('2017-02-1' ,'2017-02-28') //... chooses only pixels between the dates you define here
  .filterBounds(geometry) // ... that are within your aoi
  
print(collection) // this generates a JSON list of the images (and their metadata) which the filters found in the right-hand window.
  
/// so far this is finding all the images in the collection which meets the critera- the latest on top. To get a nice blended-looking mosaic, 
// try some of the tools for 'reducing' these to one pixel (or bands of pixels in a layer stack). 

var image = collection.median()
var image = image.clip(geometry).uint16()
var sharpened = panSharpen({
  image: image,
  bestEffort: true
})

print('sharpened', sharpened)
var visParams = {bands: 'B5,B8A,B12', min: 400, max: 4000}
Map.addLayer(image, visParams, 'image')
Map.addLayer(sharpened, visParams, 'sharpened')

/**
 * Pansharpens a Sentinel 2 image.
 * 
 * Arguments:
 * 
 * params - a client-side object containing:
 *  
 *    image (Image, required) 
 *        The image to pansharpen
 * 
 *    geometry (Geometry, default: image.geometry()) 
 *        The region to pansharpen
 * 
 *    crs (Projection, default: projection of image's first band)
 *        The projection to work in.
 * 
 *    maxPixels (Long, default: 10000000)
 *        The maximum number of pixels to reduce.
 * 
 *    bestEffort (Boolean, default: false)
 *        If the geometry would contain more pixels than maxPixels, 
 *        compute and use a larger scale which would allow the operation to succeed.
 * 
 *    tileScale (Float, default: 1)
 *        A scaling factor used to reduce aggregation tile size; 
 *        using a larger tileScale (e.g. 2 or 4) may enable computations 
 *        that run out of memory with the default.
 */
function panSharpen(params) {
  if (params && !(params.image instanceof ee.Image))
    throw Error('panSharpen(params): You must provide an params object with an image key.')

  var image = params.image
  var geometry = params.geometry || image.geometry()
  var crs = params.crs || image.select(0).projection()
  var maxPixels = params.maxPixels
  var bestEffort = params.bestEffort || false
  var tileScale = params.tileScale || 1

  image = image.clip(geometry)

  var bands10m = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8']
  var bands20m = ['B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8A', 'B11', 'B12']
 
  var panchromatic = image
    .select(bands10m)
    .reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
  Map.addLayer(panchromatic, visParams, 'panchromatic')
  var image20m = image.select(bands20m)
  Map.addLayer(image20m, visParams, 'image20m')
  var image20mResampled = image20m.resample('bilinear')
 Map.addLayer(image20mResampled, visParams, 'image20mResampled')
  var stats20m = image20m
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.stdDev().combine(
        ee.Reducer.mean(), null, true
      ),
      geometry: geometry,
      scale: 20,
      crs: crs, 
      bestEffort: bestEffort, 
      maxPixels: maxPixels, 
      tileScale: tileScale
    })
    .toImage()

  var mean20m = stats20m
    .select('.*_mean')
    .regexpRename('(.*)_mean', '$1')

  var stdDev20m = stats20m
    .select('.*_stdDev')
    .regexpRename('(.*)_stdDev', '$1')

  var kernel = ee.Kernel.fixed({
    width: 5,
    height: 5, 
    weights: [
      [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
      [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
      [-1, -1, 24, -1, -1],
      [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
      [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
    ], 
    x: -3, 
    y: -3, 
    normalize: false
  })

  var highPassFilter = panchromatic
    .convolve(kernel)
    .rename('highPassFilter')

  var stdDevHighPassFilter = highPassFilter
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
      geometry: geometry,
      scale: 10,
      crs: crs, 
      bestEffort: bestEffort, 
      maxPixels: maxPixels, 
      tileScale: tileScale
    })
    .getNumber('highPassFilter')

  function calculateOutput(bandName) {
    bandName = ee.String(bandName)
    var W = ee.Image().expression(
      'stdDev20m / stdDevHighPassFilter * modulatingFactor', {
        stdDev20m: stdDev20m.select(bandName),
        stdDevHighPassFilter: stdDevHighPassFilter,
        modulatingFactor: 0.25
      }
    )
    return ee.Image()
      .expression(
        'image20mResampled + (HPF * W)', {
          image20mResampled: image20mResampled.select(bandName),
          HPF: highPassFilter,
          W: W
      }
    )
    .uint16()
  }

  var output = ee.ImageCollection(
      bands20m.map(calculateOutput)
    )
    .toBands()
    .regexpRename('.*_(.*)', '$1')
  var statsOutput = output
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.stdDev().combine(
        ee.Reducer.mean(), null, true
      ),
      geometry: geometry,
      scale: 10,
      crs: crs, 
      bestEffort: bestEffort, 
      maxPixels: maxPixels, 
      tileScale: tileScale
    })
    .toImage()

  var meanOutput = statsOutput
    .select('.*_mean')
    .regexpRename('(.*)_mean', '$1')

  var stdDevOutput = statsOutput
    .select('.*_stdDev')
    .regexpRename('(.*)_stdDev', '$1')

  var sharpened = ee.Image()
    .expression(
      '(output - meanOutput) / stdDevOutput * stdDev20m + mean20m', {
        output: output,
        meanOutput: meanOutput,
        stdDevOutput: stdDevOutput,
        stdDev20m: stdDev20m,
        mean20m: mean20m
      }
    )
    .uint16() 
  return image
    .addBands(sharpened, null, true)
    .select(image.bandNames())
}
```

After running the code I get a blank output, I am wondering why is this happening?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use resample on a composite image.

> ee.Image.resample(mode)
>
> An algorithm that returns an image identical to its argument, but which uses bilinear or bicubic interpolation (rather than the default nearest-neighbor) to compute pixels in projections other than its native projection or other levels of the same image pyramid.
>
> This relies on the input image's default projection being meaningful, and so **cannot be used on composites**, for example. (Instead, you should resample the images that are used to create the composite.)

An alternative to resampling all the inputs is to assign a defaultProjection to the bands of the composite to match one of the inputs.  But that will only work locally, since different tiles can have different projections.

```
var first = collection.first()
var image = collection.median()

var bandsAsList = image.bandNames().map(function(name) {
  return image.select([name]).setDefaultProjection(first.select([name]).projection())
})
var image = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(bandsAsList).toBands().rename(image.bandNames())
```